# Substring error interbase

Tags: substring, interbase

I'm having some issues with the `substr` function in Interbase throwing *"a general SQL error arithmetic exception, numeric overflow or string truncation error"*.

```
select SUBSTR(note, 1, 150) note
from TABLE
```

The note field is `varchar(8192)`, but I'd like to be able to return only the first 150 characters. I am only able to write inline SQL so using a stored procedure is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most recent version of Interbase appears to be XE7 and it's [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/InterBase/XE7/en/Substr) reads:

> substr() returns the substring of  starting at position  and ending at position .
>   Note: This function can receive and return up to 80 characters, the limit on an InterBase character string.

So the overflow error is because you're passing `varchar(8192)` to function which accepts `varchar(80)`. You need to look for some other UDF lib which has a version of `substr` without this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help you much, but if you have a Note field defined as a BLOB SUB_TYPE TEXT you can do

```
select cast(note as varchar(150)) from notes
```

Unfortunately I can't find a way to use CAST on a varchar field to cast it to another varchar of smaller size - I get the error "Arithmetic error, numeric overflow or string truncation"

And of course it seems impossible to cast a varchar(8192) as a blob which you could then cast to a varchar as above!  I'm not sure whether this is ineptitude or bloody-mindedness in the design of IB's SQL.

Even more oddly, you can add a BLOB computed column to a table which has a varchar(8192) note column , as in

```
CREATE TABLE "NOTES3" 
(
  "ID"  INTEGER,
  "NOTE"    VARCHAR(8192),
  "NOTEBLOB"     COMPUTED BY (Note)
);
```

but if you then try and access the NOTEBLOB column by

```
select cast(noteblob as varchar(150)) from notes3
```

you're back to the "Arithmetic error, numeric overflow or string truncation".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firebird 2.x+ then you should use

```
select SUBSTRING(note FROM 1 FOR 150) note
from TABLE
```

This would return a BLOB Type if the field note is a BLOB.

You can also try casting the result as a varchar.

```
select cast(SUBSTRING(note FROM 1 FOR 150) as varchar(150)) note
from TABLE
```

I don´t know if this works also on Interbase.

Comment: Interbase has a SUBSTR UDF which generates the error message quoted by the OP.  It is explained in @ain's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for something else right now, but I would suspect the answer to the original question goes something like this:

```
select SUBSTR(note, 1, 75) || SUBSTR(note, 76, 75) FinalNote FROM Table
```

I am not sure how IB is going to react to a really short string (less than 75 characters long), so you may need to play with concatenating spaces to the end of "note" in the SUBSTR()'s (like I have concatenated two SUBSTR()'s).